# Vuex dispatch action inside module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

```js
// moduleA.js
const moduleA = {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}

registerSomeEvent('event', () => moduleA.dispatch('test', {data:1}));

default export moduleA;

// store.js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleA,
  }
})
```

I try to bind some event (from WebSockets) directly inside specialized module.
My problem is `moduleA.dispatch()` is not defined.. I tried to wrap it in `Vuex.store()` but then I cannot include that as module.

Comment: You want to register the event after you created your store on the store itself that includes the module, not the module itself. See the docs about [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) and [Modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html).

Comment: you registered the module as `a` not `moduleA`,  you should use it like this: `a.dispatch()`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki just a type, doesnt matter here, I was writing this here by hand

Comment: @Thinker Try `moduleA.actions.test({data:1})` or `store.dispatch('test', {data: 1})` (after initialising store).